# unable to open (or read) hostsfile mpd.hosts

Tags: mpi

I get the following error when I use this command on the cluster : mpdboot -n 4 and the error I get is:
unable to open (or read) hostsfile mpd.hosts

What does this mean, and How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to have `$HOME/mpd.hosts` unless you specify alterantive machine file.